# apache server log format change

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I edited the the httpd.conf to change the log format of apache 2.4 on my windows machine

Specifically I edited and made the following changes:

```
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat " %l %u %{%d/%b/%Y %T}t.%{msec_frac}t %{%z}t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat " %l %u %{%d/%b/%Y %T}t.%{msec_frac}t %{%z}t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

<IfModule logio_module>
  # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
  #LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
  LogFormat " %l %u %{%d/%b/%Y %T}t.%{msec_frac}t %{%z}t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>

#CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
```

But I still dont see any changes in my access.log format.

They appear as

```
192.168.1.1 - - [03/Oct/2014:11:46:21 +0200] "GET /videos/ HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Could anyone tell me how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows you have to uninstall the service like

```
httpd.exe -k uninstall 

httpd.exe -k install
```

Then the configuration is reloaded.